# Webpack 4 resolve alias with multiple possible locations

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

The source code of my project splits into two parts: shared and site specific components. It looks like that:

```
/root/
  /shared/
    component1.js
    component2.js
  /site/
    component2.js
    component3.js
```

Any component can import the other one using the following syntax:

```
component3.js:
  import Component1 from '~/component1'
  import Component2 from '~/component2'
```

I want webpack to look for any component in /site/ folder, and if it's not found, then in /shared/ folder.

I'm looking for a proper combination of webpack's resolve alias and modules to achieve that.

1. Currently I use a lot of symlinks. So the link to component1 placed in site folder, and the last folder specified as webpack entry point. It works, but there's a huge mess of symlinks in the real project.
2. I want ~ path to have two aliases: /site/ and /shared/. Something like that:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~': ['/path/to/site', '/path/to/shared']
  }
}
```

But it does not work since alias value should be string.

3. Let's try modules:

```
modules: [
  '/path/to/site',
  '/path/to/shared',
  'node_modules'
]
```

The import command will change to `import Component1 from 'component1'`. It seems to work, but what if some of my component has the same name as some package in node_modules? I have to distinct them somehow.

Comment: I think you can do this Webpack's [`enhanced-resolve`](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve) plugin, as of the PR described in [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6817)